# Source for tossing grass over the shoulder while leaving the cemetery

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, cemetery-grave

There is a custom by many to toss some grass over their shoulder while leaving a cemetery. What are the origins of this custom?

Comment: How do you know about this custom? Have you seen it? Who have you seen doing it?

Comment: @mevaqesh - I'll need to locate it but I have seen a video of the Rebbe doing it by his mother's grave.